# Does different distributions i.e. t, χ2, F, calculate p values converting respect distribution to Normal distribution?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, normal-distribution, normalization

As each distributions i.e.  t, χ2, F, have their own way to calculate statistic using tables, When we using software to calculate p value for them, Does the software convert respect distribution to Normal distribution for calculating the p value?

Comment: You would need to ask this for each software system but the broad answer is no. For instance R calculates chi-squared using the gamma distribution.

Comment: What library are you referring to?

Comment: It’s not particularly about a library. Any software, R, JMP, Minitab, or GraphPad. I am interested to learn how p value is calculated for each different distribution. For each distribution has it’s own table to look up the values manually . However I haven’t come across how does p value is calculated in each distribution. I presume each distribution would transfer to ND, because p value is range from 1-0.

Comment: I suggest you open your installation of R and type ?pchisq and ?pf and follow the references in the help pages. This is not as simple as you suggest.

Comment: In all these cases a conversion to Normality would be *more difficult* than working with the distributions directly.